# How to add country code dynamically in telephone field on Checkout in Magento 2

Tags: layout, knockoutjs, plugin, helper, custom-block

I want to develop custom module that is used for adding country code field before telephone field on checkout page in magento 2.3.4.

Comment: This is the Final Answer of this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222229/magento-2-checkout-knockout-js-in-custom-template-error-telephone-field

Comment: Add customization in telephone field using Knockout Js: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222229/magento-2-checkout-knockout-js-in-custom-template-error-telephone-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the some free and paid extension available, you can use it:

Free - https://github.com/MaxMage/international-telephone-input

Paid - https://magery-themes.com/intl-tel-input-magento2.html

[https://magecomp.com/magento-2-international-telephone-input.html#:~:text=Magento%202%20Internationa...](https://magecomp.com/magento-2-international-telephone-input.html#:%7E:text=Magento%202%20Internationa...).

Thanks

Comment: But I want to build custom module and don't want to use any paid extensions.

Comment: This one is free, Free - https://github.com/MaxMage/international-telephone-input

Comment: But it's not working fine.. - Vibhore Jain

Comment: @DeepShah Inside Block/PhoneNumber.php file comment or remove this line, "preferredCountries" => [$this->helper->preferedCountry()]. and then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below extension, it automatically adds validation based on the selected country with the country flags and automatically sets the user country by default based on their Geo IP location. It is also supported with the latest Magento 2.4.5 version as well.

https://marketplace.magento.com/ananta-module-telephonevalidation.html